# Single responsibility principle and right way to organize interfaces for DI

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, dependency-injection, interface

Suppose you have files which are stored on disk and you need to load them. Files are of 3 types with extensions `*.ext1`, `*.ext2` and `*.ext3`. So I have three `load` methods, each of them should be synchronized by different lock. I should inject somehow this behavior into my service with DI framework. *Which of the ways below are better?*

It seems the first way is an obvious. But what makes me uncertain - principle of single responsibility and the fact you'll never want to load all three extensions: you will load only 1 & 3 or only 2 & 3.

***1) General interface for all file types loader:***

```
public interface FileLoader {
    void loadFilesOfExt1();
    void loadFilesOfExt2();
    void loadFilesOfExt3();
}

//The most obvoius solution, but doesn't it break the principle of single responsibility?
//It also has one more dwawback - I want to synchronize each method by different lock, and it requires using of locks
public class FileLoaderImpl implements FileLoader {
    public void loadFilesOfExt1() { /* impl */ }
    public void loadFilesOfExt2() { /* impl */ }
    public void loadFilesOfExt3() { /* impl */ 
}
```

***2) Specific Interface for each type of files:***

```
//It looks pretty weird to have three interfaces with the same API
public interface Ext1Loader { void load(); }
public interface Ext2Loader { void load(); }
public interface Ext3Loader { void load(); }
public class Ext1LoaderImpl extends Ext1Loader { public synchronized void load() { /* impl */ } }
public class Ext2LoaderImpl extends Ext2Loader { public synchronized void load() { /* impl */ } }
public class Ext3LoaderImpl extends Ext3Loader { public synchronized void load() { /* impl */ } }
```

***3) Hierarchy of interfaces:***

```
//Isn't it an overengeneering? 3 Empty interfaces
public interface FileLoader { void load(); }
public interface Ext1Loader extends FileLoader {}
public interface Ext2Loader extends FileLoader {}
public interface Ext3Loader extends FileLoader {}
public class Ext1LoaderImpl extends Ext1Loader { public synchronized void load() { /* impl */ } }
public class Ext2LoaderImpl extends Ext2Loader { public synchronized void load() { /* impl */ } }
public class Ext3LoaderImpl extends Ext3Loader { public synchronized void load() { /* impl */ } }
```

***4) Single interface:***

```
//This makes me feel like all implementations `Ext1Loader`, `Ext2Loader` and `Ext3Loader` are interchangable. 
//But actually you may want to inject `Ext1Loader` nad `Ext3Loader` simultaneously into your class
public interface FileLoader { public void load(); }
public class Ext1Loader implements FileLoader { public synchronized void load() { /* impl */ } }
public class Ext2Loader implements FileLoader { public synchronized void load() { /* impl */ } }
public class Ext3Loader implements FileLoader { public synchronized void load() { /* impl */ } }
```

Comment: Why don't you just take the `FileLoader` interface and make `Ext1Loader` the implementation?

Comment: @RolandIllig pls look at the fourth way, I forgot to cover it

Comment: @V_B, do you have `FileExt1`, `FileExt2` classes or some file hierarchy?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko no, I just need to parse those files into `Map`. That are files of very trivial format, no need for separate file class  hierarchy

Comment: what DI framework do you use? can I provide my viewpoint with Spring?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Google Guice or Spring doesn't matter. Yeah, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third solution looks like the sanest solution here. But adding marker interfaces which do nothing seems to be an overengineering.

I would suggest you consider my viewpoint of your task:

```
public interface FileLoader {
    void load();
}
```

There is only one interface, implementations which will present loading a file of a specific format. Each loader has a unique name that describes which file type the loader will work with.

```
@Component("Ext1")
public class Ext1FileLoader implements FileLoader {
    public synchronized void load() {}
}
```

After that, we need a factory that produces loaders on demand.

```
@Component
public class FileLoaderFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    // to get new loaders
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    // to keep already pulled out instances
    private Map<String, FileLoader> loaders;

    public FileLoader getFileLoaderByFileType(String type) {
        // trying to use a lazy-loading mode

        return loaders.get(type) == null ? getFromContext(type) : loaders.get(type);
    }

    private FileLoader getFromContext(String type) {
        // getting a bean from the context, putting it into a map and returning a value

        FileLoader loader = context.getBean(type, FileLoader.class);
        loaders.put(type, loader);
        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        // a casting here is to get broader functionality from a context instance

        this.context = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) context;
    }

}
```

---

*The following solution could have been more concise, but we wouldn't have been able to turn a lazy-init mode on. Take  a look:*

```
@Component
class FileLoaderFactory {

    // it would collect all loaders available in the content
    private @Autowired Map<String, FileLoader> loaders;

    public FileLoader getFileLoaderByFileType(String type) {
        return loaders.get(type);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a factory class to provide generic load function like,

   public Class FileLoader {

   //Define a map like

   private Map extensionToLoaderMap;

   public static File load(StringfilePath) {

   // Extract extension and get appropriate loader from Map

   // do something meaningful here.

   }
2. Define one interface say,

   public interface ExtensionLoader {

   public File loadExtension(String filePath);

   }
3. Now you can define as many extension loaders as possible.
4. You can use your DI framework to store all these mappings like, as described [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-collections-list-set-map-and-properties-example/) for spring framework

This will enable you to add/modify functionality of extension loaders without modifying java code of actual file loader.

Comment: Hint: when putting up source code - make sure it is formatted correctly as source code! If you don't know how that works - better study the help on markup!

Comment: Hint 2: code inside lists needs double-indentation to format correctly.